# Is there a way skip lines till a specific string is seen, when reading in excel file with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, xlsx

(edited) I have an excel file containing billing information, and would like to skip unnecessary rows before the actual rows containing the bills.

The data is in this format

**customer id**

**customer info**

....

....

**payment info**

....

....

...

**payment & adjustment**

...

**Tax invoice**

**actual rows containing bills**

I have tried

`pd.read_excel('bills.xlsx', skiprows = 100,index_col=None)`

but the bill format is inconsistent in a way that other bills may contain more than 100 unnecessary rows before the actual information, is there a way to skip rows until a row containing a particular string(e.g Tax invoice)?

Comment: Please add an example of your data.

Comment: How do the lines to be skipped look like? Empty?

Comment: I've added an example of my data , to give a better description.

Comment: The whole data is in one column?

Comment: it has multiple columns